# Show date in ui-grid table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I use ui-grid in my project to show some data and dates.

The example of date from ajax call is:

```
 DateReview='06/25/2016'
```

the format is mm/dd/yyyy in this format date is displayed.

Here the defenition of the ui-grid column:

```
   name: 'Start date', field: 'DateReview', cellTooltip: true, headerTooltip: true, width: 90 }
```

I need the date to be displayed in ui-grid in this format:

```
dd/mm/yyyy
```

Any idea what is elegant way to change format of the displayed date in ui-gris column?

Answer (score 2):

Here ya go:

```
{ name: 'Start date', field: 'DateReview', cellTooltip: true, headerTooltip: true, width: 90, type: 'date', cellFilter: "date:\'dd/MM/yyyy\'"}
```